# jQuery web service call unsuccessful

Tags: jquery, web-services

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function hello() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld2",
            data: "{ 'pstrName': 'steven' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('S');
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Any problem with the above jQuery call?  Why it always run into the error function?

I am using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.4, please help. Thanks.

Comment: what is the error massage has been alerted?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: `data: { 'pstrName': 'steven' },`

Answer (score 1):

This (no need for the outer quotes)

```
data: { 'pstrName': 'steven' },
```

Comment: I have try remove the outer quotes, but still the same. And I call this jQuery with an asp:Button (<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="hello();" />)

Comment: Are you sure this is a jQuery issues? if you get an alert box with a message of 'error', then that means the alert(textStatus) inside of your error function is trigged. try to console log the XMLHttpRequest Object inside of the error function. if you see something in the console, then that means the jQuery code is working fine and the error is coming from the server.